# Utilizing switch statements with enums and marker interface

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I've got a marker interface

```
public interface Marker{}
```

and two enums which implement the Marker

```
public enum Sharpie implements Marker{
    RED,
    BLUE,
    BLACK
}

public enum Crayola implements Marker{
    PURPLE,
    ORANGE,
    GREEN
}
```

What I'm trying to do is utilize a switch statement, such as

```
public boolean isOwned(Marker m){
    // Take in a marker of either Sharpie, or Crayola
    switch(m){
        case BLUE:
        case BLACK:
        case GREEN:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using an expensive `instanceof` call?

Something like this would work, but I'm trying to avoid using `instanceof`, and frankly it looks kind of ugly.

```
public boolean isOwned(Marker m){

    // First determine instanceof and then cast the marker 
    // to the appropriate Type before utilizing the switch statement
    if (m instanceof Sharpie){
       switch((Sharpie) m){
           Case BLUE:
           Case BLACK:
               return true;
           default:
               return false;
       }
    } else {
       switch((Crayola) m){
           case Green:
               return true;
           default:
               return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe don't make your interface a marker. Make it expose an `isOwned()` API method, which will be implemented by your enums. That way, you'd get rid of the `switch` altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately, the idea is that different markers will be owned by different "people". This information would be determined by individual "people". Perhaps, a better name would be `doesOwn()` as different instances would own different markers.
Having the enum implement this method wouldn't allow for this.

Comment: Still, you can use `Marker` to make enums expose unique values across all implementations. If, for example,  each enum could expose a `String getUniqueColor()` method, your external `isOwned()` method would be able to even use a `switch` without depending on the runtime type of your `Marker` arguments.

Comment: What @user16320675 is suggesting is also what I would expect implementation-wise: have each person own a `Set<Marker>` and then use `contains()`. Alternatively, to implement the logic that you currently have, you could just use a static  `Map<Marker, Boolean>` and use that to look up the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a good scenario to try new Java Feature [Sealed Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html) and [Pattern Matching for switch Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html)(* this is a preview feature as at jdk 17)

First make `Marker` as sealed interface

```
public sealed interface Marker permits Crayola, Sharpie {}
```

Then we can use switch expression to get rid of those `instanceof` checking.

```
    public boolean isOwned(Marker marker) {
        boolean isOwned = switch (marker) {
            case Sharpie s -> s == Sharpie.BLACK || s == Sharpie.BLUE;
            case Crayola c -> c == Crayola.GREEN;
        };
        return isOwned;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: That's good to know! I'll accept this answer. However, I actually went with a Set<> approach as other comments suggested since I'm limited to Java 8.

Comment: @user15708369 FYI there is also an [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) (if not already using it)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `switch` to `if`. There is no need for `instanceof`:

```
public boolean isOwned(Marker m){
    if(m == Sharpie.BLUE || m == Sharpie.BLACK || m == Crayola.GREEN)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what are you doing. this example is using unique function for 2 diffrents enum. i think you should use extending in enum [like this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-extending-enums).